# Does Exchange server uses Certificate to validate client?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am creating an EWS service which will connect to the **Exchange server 2007**. I am using **Autodiscover** service of Exchange server.I need to understand following:

- How can I validate the SSL/TSL certificates for my service.
- I need to know conventional way how outlook communicate with Exchange server.
- How to Detect the specific certificate is installed for authentication.

I had written the code to connect to the Exchange server.But I am facing issues with the Certificate part.I am totally confused with the proper handshake with help of certificate.

In my code I had used **X509Store** to get the certificate stores and then validate from the server,but the certificate may differ from server to server (Exchange).Is there any way around.

Comment: Please add comment so that i could get an approach..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a targeted question and answer site. Its not built for high level questions like you asked. Its kind of expected you have the requisite background knowledge.